# R global options appearance reverts to default on its own

Tags: r, appearance

Does anyone know why this is happening? I just got a new desktop & just installed R. I usually work with dark-colour appearance background. It's reverting back to default white colour. Probably due to long minutes of inactivity, but this never happened before.

Comment: Apologies...
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) -- "Action of the Toes"
R studio
OS is Windows 10* 64-bit
Not reproducible. it's just the appearance reverting back to default white, after I've changed it to Night Blue

Comment: ok thanks.  May be somebody else with the same config would comment.  I am on R 3.6.2 on mac